# Assign a specific enum to Class<Enum> in Java

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I have an enum, and I want to convert the class into `Class<Enum>` without reflection.

For example, the enum is Numbers.java

```
public enum Numbers {
    ONE, TWO, THREE;
}
```

The best I can do is using reflection, as follow

```
Class<Enum> enumClass = (Class<Enum>) Class.forName("com.package.inner.eveninner.Numbers");
```

Is there any way to do it without using reflection?

```
Class<Enum> enumClass = (Class<Enum>) Numbers.class;
```

gives an compile error:

`incompatible types: Class<Numbers> cannot be converted into Class<Enum>`

Comment: Why not `Class<Numbers>`?

Comment: There is no "conversion" to speak of. If you want to reference your `enum` as a class, you can simply use `Numbers.class`, which is a `Class<Numbers>`. Not quite sure what you're trying to do though.

Comment: You can't. But why do you even need to do anything like this?

Comment: Also, reflection doesn't "convert" anything. Ever.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul i need it to implement this one https://anismiles.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/postgres-enum-with-hibernate/
Notice the setParameterValues function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` instead.

```
public enum Numbers {
    ONE, TWO, THREE;
}
public void test(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass = Numbers.class;
    System.out.println(enumClass);
}
```

Comment: Why is it unlikely? `Class<Enum>` exists in JDK, in `java.lang` package.

Comment: @Hulk Do you think there's a difference between `Class<Enum>` and, say `Class<Enum<ABC>>`?

Comment: @Hulk, no `Class` can be directly instantiated, be it a `Class<E extends Enum<E>>` or `Class<Object>`. Class can only be loaded. And `Class<Enum>` does exist. At runtime there would not be any information changes to it either. Take `java.lang.Enum.class` and inspect it.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Ok, I see what you mean